# How to run bitnami debian 9 inbuilt component cakephp run on custom domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I have bitnami lamp set up on google cloud instance.
I am using inbuild CakePHP component that runs on  "IP/cakephp" url. i want to run on ip or www.example-domain.com, not on subdomain (/cakephp). how can i do that?

IP is points to my htdocs folder. but inbuild cakephp is no opt/bitnami/framewords/cackephp folder.

Note: I don't want to move it to htdocs folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Thanks for using Bitnami. You will need to modify the Apache's configuration under /opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf and set the DocumentRoot to the cakephp folder. You will also need to remove the Alias lines from the configuration file and then restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```